# Show hide directive one at a time - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am creating a tooltip for my directive, but somehow either all four will appear or none on click in green div. Let me know what I am doing wrong here.

Working Plnkr - https://plnkr.co/edit/Rk2hMz6gmKPlN3IhKMYE?p=preview

**HTML -**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>    
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="mainCtrl"> 
    <div class="con-div" ng-repeat="row in fakeDataSet" ng-click="data.clicked = !data.clicked">
        <test-div click-val="data.clicked"></test-div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**JavaScript -**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope){

    $scope.fakeDataSet = [1,2,3,4];
    $scope.data = {};
    $scope.data.clicked =  false;
});

myApp.directive('testDiv', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        scope: {
            clickVal: "="
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs){
            console.log("clickVal", scope.clickVal);
        },
        template: '<div class="tooltip" ng-if="clickVal">This is a tooltip</div>'
    };  
})
```

Comment: you are binding all the 4 instances of the directive to the same scope. clickVal will always be bounded to data.clicked, which will be the same value being fed into all the directives. If you want separate behaviour, you need to make properties for each of the instances

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are binding all the 4 instances of the directive to the same scope. Something like this will make a separate state for each of your instances. If you bind your click event to a function, that resets all the truthy/falsys before setting the active, it will only keep one open.

```
<div class="con-div" ng-repeat="row in fakeDataSet" ng-click="setToolTip(row)">
    <test-div click-val="data.clicked[row]"></test-div>
</div>

$scope.fakeDataSet = [1,2,3,4];
$scope.data = {};
$scope.data.clicked =  {1: false, 2: false, 3: false, 4:false};

$scope.setToolTip = function(row){
    Object.keys($scope.data.clicked).forEach(function(elem){
        $scope.data.clicked[elem] = false;      
    });
    $scope.data.clicked[row] = true;
}
```

Comment: I tried your code but its not working...It will keep the others open as well - https://plnkr.co/edit/Rk2hMz6gmKPlN3IhKMYE?p=preview

Comment: you never specified what behaviour was expected, do you want it to be constrained to only one element visible at a time?

Comment: yes I already mentioned this in title - `Show hide directive one at a time`

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/4haMJMIaraCzzP4rHtzt?p=preview

Just bind it to a function that resets all the others before setting the clicked one to true

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change it to:

```
ng-click="data.clicked[row] = !data.clicked[row]">
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/iYAtHmRSHKnpNy1CBRG3?p=preview

Comment: this will still keep the other tooltips active if not clicked again

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have binded same click value with each element due to which all the tooltip are shown/hide together.

```
<div class="con-div" ng-repeat="row in fakeDataSet" ng-click="row.clicked = !row.clicked">
    <test-div click-val="row.clicked"></test-div>
</div>

$scope.fakeDataSet = [{value : 1, clicked : false},
{value : 2, clicked : false},
{value : 3, clicked : false},
{value : 4, clicked : false}];
```

Comment: This will still keep the others active if not clicked again, see this https://plnkr.co/edit/Rk2hMz6gmKPlN3IhKMYE?p=preview